# .NET configure server certificate for an application

Tags: c#, .net, https

I am totally new to .NET and I came across one problem that is related to an agent application.
Its an IoT agent application which will be deployed and run Windows and Linux systems.

The application is a Web Service based application and uses HTTPS certificate to enable the secure communication between the clients and agent. When I tried to run the application on one of the system, I got error as

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found.
```

After going through most of the posts, I found that we need to download and install the `'dotnet'` run time on the system and run below commands

```
dotnet dev-certs https
dotnet dev-certs https --check
```

However, for development environment its okay to run these commands. I am looking for a solution where we can run the application without download and installing the `dotnet` runtime environment.

What are the initial configuration settings those may required to run the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the runtime you are missing (you wouldn't be able to execute the application and get the exception). You are missing a valid certificate for your server.

On a development machine you would issue the command

```
 dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

to install a trusted self signed certificate. On a production server you have to install a certificate from your certificate server or if it's public accessible from a trusted certificate authority.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for your answer. Surely, I will try to get the details about how we can get the server certificate.

Comment: Hi Peter, after going through the details, I found that the application is using the KestrelServer. I think it require the HTTPS config settings into the webserver configurations. Please correct me here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, able to run the application on Windows 7 and Windows 10 machine with the PFX certificate.

You need to generate the certificate. You may follow below link to generate the certificate.

https://www.sslsupportdesk.com/export-ssl-certificate-private-key-pfx-using-mmc-windows/

It is required to configure the Kestrel settings in JSON file. Below is the possible JSON configuration to use the certificate

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:9448",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "path/to/certificate/file/your-cert.pfx",
          "Password": "PwdOfCert",
          "AllowInvalid": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```